# Truth functional propositional logic for "If" in Hunter's Metalogic

Tags: logic

[image: problem (e)]

[image: solution (e)]

I encountered a weird question in Hunter's *Metalogic*.

**Here's my reasoning:**

'If' in 'If Tom marries Mary, Susan will be unhappy', according to Hunter, is not a "truth functional propositional connective" because we are missing the key 'then' in the 'If...then' conditional statement.

Consider that the statement "If Tom marries Mary" is true and "Susan will be unhappy" is also true. Then we can't determine the truth value of "If Tom marries, Susan will be unhappy" because we are missing the key phrase "then" that makes a conditional.

I feel like this is wrong, because in the solution, it says "If A then B" which is a conditional statement.

Does the context of the specific conditions of the question influence in the truth value? For instance, if Tom marries Mary, and Susan is unhappy, then we can't determine the conditional relationship between these conditions? But that seems like it's a causal connection, not a an 'if...then' statement.

**But that still seems wrong,** because the solution still says "If...then" and also a causal connection is usually not inferred in logic, right?

Help! What is going on?

Comment: Hunter's explanation is "strange" ... It seems that, according to him, the context of the sentence does not allow for a truth-functional "modelization".

Comment: Interesting, could you elaborate?

Comment: You can see e.g. [Conditionals](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/conditionals/#TruConIndCon)